# Android crash in mysterious d() method

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, generated-code

Got a Play Store crash report (hooray). The stack trace lists an NPE occurring in `MyActivity#d()`, inside of `MyAtivity#onCreate()`. Is this a compiler-generated method? I sure didn't write it!

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.MyActivity.d(Unknown Source)
at com.example.MyActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should at least post `onCreate`.

Comment: Did you run proguard on your project?

Comment: Looks like the code was obfuscated, so you can't tell much about this stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably did run pro guard (the Google obfuscation) when you made the build. 
Look for a file called mapping.txt it will give you the real name of the d() method.

mapping.txt:
Lists the mapping between the original and obfuscated class, method, and field names. This file is important when you receive a bug report from a release build, because it translates the obfuscated stack trace back to the original class, method, and member names.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) for more.